# How to improve layout and design when having different fill-out components?

Tags: usability, user-expectation, user-centered-design, affordance, standards

There are different types of information requirements: drop down menus, text input, picture upload and radio buttons. Is there a standards or research supporting the idea to put certain requirements before others to improve usability and completion rates? (e.g. putting the more complicated parts before)

[image]

Comment: The question has been reworded, I did not mean to make it particular to this case. It was an example to understand the best standards and design habits to create complex fill-out forms. I would like to learn how to improve the ways forms are designed to increase completion rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Layout Critiques

- Placing UI elements horizontally on mobile is a bad idea. With smaller screen sizes, the elements will be harder to see
- Some users may "fat finger" buttons that are closely positioned
- Can the product name be inferred from the bar code? If so, consider removing the bar code line entirely and instead move the bar code button next to the product text entry
- **Be consistent.** Do you want your elements aligned to the left or centered? It doesn't matter which you choose, just stick with it.
- Visually separate your top bar from the rest of the content. Consider adding a solid filled background.
- Fill up the unused whitespace. There is an enormous gap between your two buttons at the bottom that serves no purpose.

## Color Critiques

- **Choose a palette.** Your primary color seems to be orange, so you may want all of your primary actions to "be orange". This would mean changing the `Guardar` button to the same shade of orange as your title text.
- You are using four very different colors in one page. People associate color with meaning, so avoid using "loud" or "strong" colors and instead opt for more neutral colors or different shades of a similar color.

Answer (score 0):

**Test it with users.** You could consult a visual designer (or Graphic Design Stack Exchange) for tips on layout and colors and such, but the best way to assess whether this is usable or not—and *why* or *why not*, more importantly—is to watch people using it and ask them questions about their experience with it.

Here are some resources that can help you get started with user testing:

- [Usability 101](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/usability-101-introduction-to-usability/) by Jakob Nielsen
- [Running a Usability Test](https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/running-usability-tests.html) on Usability.gov
- [How to Conduct a Usability Test](http://uxmastery.com/beginners-guide-to-usability-testing/) on UX Mastery

(UX.SE vets, feel free to curate this list.)